# How can I style jQuery draggable clone?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I style jQuery draggable clone with CSS?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

*Refer to second answer by tohster - this is outdated.*

=======

http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2008/09/jquery-ui-draggables-helper-css-class.html this might be a help

Quoting from the above site:

> While working with [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggables/draggable) draggables, I have noticed that there does not seem to be a class associated with the draggable helper, and so it is styled in the same way as the draggable you selected. As a result you have to resort to the start function option to add the class dynamically:

```
$(".dragme").draggable({helper: "clone",
 start: function(e, ui)
 {
  $(ui.helper).addClass("ui-draggable-helper");
 }
});
```

> As a result you have to resort to the start function option to add the class dynamically:

```
.ui-draggable-helper {
 border: 1px dotted #000;
 padding: 6px;
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Note - this is correct BUT if you use CSS to resize the cloned item it appears to mess up the positioning of the helper as you drag.

Comment: my element is big, this solution helps me reduce opacity so i can see things below. tks

Answer (score 25):

### There's a better way

jQuery UI has evolved since the answer was posted in 2011.

With current versions of jQuery, the `.ui-draggable-dragging` class is added to the clone being dragged.

So for example, if you have the following draggable element:

```
<div class="myDraggable">
</div>

<script>
   $('.myDraggable').draggable({opacity: 0.7, helper: "clone"});
</script>

<style>
   .myDraggable.ui-draggable-dragging { background: red; }
</style>
```

..then the myDraggable element clone will have a red background when it is picked up and dragged.

The helper class is present in jQuery UI 1.7.1 onwards, and it may also be present in some earlier versions but I haven't tracked that down.

Answer (score 2):

The cleaner approach is to use helper function:

```
function getHelper(event, ui) {
    var helper = $(ui).clone();
    helper.addClass("ui-draggable-helper");
    return helper;
}

$('.myDraggable').draggable({
    helper: getHelper
});
```

Comment: How can method getHelper be called? I've got errors with this code.