# jquery UI draggable grid make it visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jquery ui draggable allows you to create a grid on which you can snap draggable elements to.

How can I display the grid? I find that the grid is different from what I expect and some way to make it visible would be helpful.

This is my grid:

http://cl.ly/image/2W372D1e0U27

Except when it moves future down it's totally wrong.

It's not off by a little and then builds up, it's just completely wrong for 1 area in the grid.

You see it being correct here:

http://cl.ly/image/2N3S1Y432b3Z

Move down 1 unit:

http://cl.ly/image/3V3E290I0f1H

Completely wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208673/how-to-draw-grid-using-html5-and-canvas-or-svg

Comment: @Ruben I already have a grid. I want to compare my grid to jquery ui's grid.

Comment: do you mean style the clone that is being dragged> Like give it background? This post gives good way to create class for helper [how-can-i-style-jquery-draggable-clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489794/how-can-i-style-jquery-draggable-clone)

Comment: I believe a background will be enough.

Comment: Okay time for image, i'll update the original post.

Comment: @Harry, please update your question and upload the pictures not on external sites. Also it would be helpful if you add your code to your question.

Comment: @Harry Please review the answer I posted and if needed, update your post with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the use of `grid` option in jQuery UI Draggable. It snaps the drag element to an X and Y Axis based on a number of pixels. There is no grid or set of elements in the DOM, just a calculation based on the position of the draggable element in relationship to it's parent or the document.

Your post does not include any proper example, only screen shots. So there is no good way to know what the HTML looks like. Here is a basic example I created, hopefully it is similar to your code.

```js
$(function() {
  var gs = parseInt($("#gs").val()),
    sq = parseInt($("#sq").val()),
    cRows = $(".drag-zone").height() / gs,
    cCols = $(".drag-zone").width() / gs;

  function drawGridLines(r, c, b) {
    /*
    input: Rows Integer, Cols integer, Buffer Integer
    output: null
    Based on the number or Rows and Cols, draw gridlines with a single buffer space between.
    */
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
      $("<div>", {
        class: "row"
      }).css({
        height: (b - 1) + "px",
        width: "100%",
        top: (b * i) + "px"
      }).insertBefore($(".drag-zone"));
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      $("<div>", {
        class: "col"
      }).css({
        width: (b - 1) + "px",
        height: "100%",
        left: (b * i) + "px"
      }).insertBefore($(".drag-zone"));
    }
  }

  function makeSquare(s, tObj) {
    /*
    input: Size Integer, Target jQuery Object
    output: null
    Create a square div element with class 'item' and append it to the Target.
    */
    $("<div>", {
      class: "item"
    }).css({
      width: s + "px",
      height: s + "px"
    }).appendTo(tObj);
  }

  function makeDrag(obj, b) {
    /*
    input: jQuery Object, Buffer Integer
    output: null
    Initialize the jQuery Object with Draggable, using specific options for square Grid spacing
    */
    obj.draggable({
      containment: "parent",
      grid: [b, b]
    })
  }

  drawGridLines(cRows, cCols, gs);
  makeSquare(sq, $(".drag-zone"));
  makeDrag($(".item"), gs);

  $("#go-btn").click(function() {
    var ngs = parseInt($("#gs").val()),
      nsq = parseInt($("#sq").val()),
      rw = $(".drag-zone").height() / ngs,
      cl = $(".drag-zone").width() / ngs;
    $(".row, .col, .item").remove();
    if (nsq < 2) {
      nsq = 2;
    }
    drawGridLines(rw, cl, ngs);
    makeSquare(nsq, $(".drag-zone"));
    makeDrag($(".item"), ngs);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
}

p input {
 width: 40px;
}

.grid {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.drag-zone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.item {
  background: red;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  left: 0;
}

.col {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Gutter Size: <input id="gs" type="text" value="20" /> Square Size: <input id="sq" type="text" value="60" /> <button id="go-btn">Redraw</button>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="drag-zone">
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see, the rows and columns have grid lines at 50 pixel increment to form a grid in the background. I placed another div on top but it'd not exactly necessary.

We initialize draggable with containment, to remain in the grid confines, and with the grid option, set to the width / height of our square. Movement of the draggable item snaps to the grid lines.

You can also use `snap` if you want less jerky movement yet to remain attached to the grid lines. In your use case, this would not be advisable since it can leave the item floating if it does not intersect with a border.

You could also write a `stop` function that examines the positions and moves it to the nearest grid lines. This gives a more free movement effect and then snaps when released. You can even animate it sliding into position.

It was not clear if you wanted each cell in the grid to be addressable. You could make a large array of div elements and make them all droppable. In this way, the user drags the element without the snapping, yet when they drop the item, it could append itself to the div.

Hope that helps.