# 'this' refers to drag element in case of cloning

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to refer the cloned element in a drag handler. The following code does not work and refers to main object , not the cloned one

```
$(elem).draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    drag: function () {
        console.log('$(this) refers to the original not the one that is cloned')
    }
})
```

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489794/how-can-i-style-jquery-draggable-clone), may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ui.helper selector.

```
 $(ui.helper)
```